# get CSS from chrome dev tools as JavaScript object value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

we just start to write styles in our react components using [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) hook from material-ui.

so the css now is not regular css but js object - looks something like this for exmple:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
 createStyles({
     root: {
         display: 'flex'
     },
     divider:{
         width:'1px',
         backgroundColor:'rgba(44, 66, 107, 0.15)'
     }
 }),
);
```

no, before - when we use scss files sometimes i "play" with the styles on the chrome dev tools:

[image]
and when it's ok I copy->paste it to the scss file.

when I try to do the same here I get regular CSS that not valid in js object:
[image]

and need to change it manually to be valid as js object value:
[image]

(in this example is very little manually change but it other examples it can be a lot of changes...

looking for a way to get the styles from chrome dev tools as "JS" CSS styles and not "regular" CSS like now.
surely I can use some manual solution like this great one:

https://css2js.dotenv.dev/

but I want to avoid all this copy-paste

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

> allows you to write actual CSS code to style your components.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  color: grey;
`;
```

---

Refer: MUI official document suggestion: https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components